# Can't change swing window location dynamically

Tags: scala-swing

I want to change scala-swing window location.
I found setting location works correctly when initialization but can't change location dynamically

```scala
import java.awt.Point

import scala.swing._
import scala.swing.event.ButtonClicked

object TestWindow extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  def top = new MainFrame {
    contents = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {
      contents += new Button("Change location") {
        reactions += {
          case e: ButtonClicked => {
            println("change location")
            top.location = new Point(200, 100)//doesn't work
            println("change location end")
          }
        }
      }
    }
    location = new Point(100, 50) //works correctly
  }
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved using following statement:

```scala
this.peer.getRootPane.getParent.setLocation(new Point(200, 100))
```

here `this.peer` is reference to java JButton, `getRootPane` gives you placeholder of the button, then in this particular case `getParent` gets your `MainFrame` object (may need to use more than one `getParent` if hierachy is bigger). I think by using `top.location` you are trying to create a new `MainFrame` which is likely to be prohibited by API.